# DocBook: Suppress Section in PDF Output

Tags: xml, pdf, xsl-fo, docbook

I'm working with a DocBook that has a Chapter or Section on Revisions.

Management does not want the section in the final PDF document. They feel the revision numbers leak a history of problems. I want the section for internal tracking, and I'm all for transparency.

If I simply comment the section, it does not show up under the editors. So the revision history might not be updated because its not present.

Goggling is producing pages on removing the "Chapter" and "Section" prefix from the header's title, and not the result I seek.

How do I suppress the output of a chapter or section in the final PDF document, while leaving it in the sources?

Comment: Did you try profiling? http://sagehill.net/docbookxsl/Profiling.html

Comment: Can you add a small example, of your DocBook XML. Which shows a example of the full issue and describes what should and should not be seen in the final document(s). It sounds like you'll want to have two XSL's. One for creating an internal used PDF and one which can be shipped to customers.